# C# compile error for simple Annual Salary Calculator

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to create my 1st app.
I have 3 errors. The first two say that txtSalary and Salary do not exist. 
The 3rd says that it

> cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'.

and asks if I intend to invoke the method.

Here is what I have:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    int salary, AnnualHours, Rate;
    string txtAnnualHours, txtSalary, txtRate;

    salary = AnnualHours * Rate;
    txtsalary = int.Parse(Salary); 
    txtAnnualHours = salary.ToString; 
    MessageBox.Show(salary); 
}
```

According to my book, when you enter numerics in `AnnualHours` and `Rate` textbox, when click `Button1`, these values are converted from string to integers, then multiplied for salary.
Then numeric answer converted to string and displayed in messagebox named `txtSalary`.

Please show me what I got wrong because according to the book, I am not missing anything.

Comment: You have not assigned values to `AnnualHours` or `Rate` and you have `Salary` in the Parse call when it should be `salary`. Among other problems.

Comment: You are trying to use variables before being initialized. Can we have the name of your other text-boxes that represent those other variables?

Comment: And also `ToString` needs parentheses because it is a method: `salary.ToString()`

Comment: If the code you posted is the exact code from your book, get a new book.

Comment: Your code has all sorts of errors... There is a basic lack of understanding in how to solve the problem here.  You stated that you have textboxes that the user enters values into to perform your calculations, but your function doesn't actually ever use the textbox values, you instead create entirely empty variables that can't possibly calculate anything.  You should study a bit more some examples of reading values from textboxes and try to think a bit more about how the function relates to the other pieces of your program.  Also, C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    int salary, AnnualHours = 0, Rate = 0;
    string txtAnnualHours, txtSalary, txtRate;

    salary = AnnualHours * Rate;
    txtSalary = salary.ToString();
    txtAnnualHours = salary.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(salary);
}
```

For error of MessageBox you need to do write this at the top of your cs file.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: `txtSalary` and `txtAnnualHours` are declared as `string`, not `TextBox`.

Comment: Nikhil, your input is the MOST correct. When I edited my code by giving the variables value as you showed, I now get only ONE error, which says "The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context." Being a newbie, I have no clue why since it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Well this line

```
txtsalary = int.Parse(Salary);
```

Is not only incorrect, but unnecessary. txtsalary is a string and int.Parse returns an int - these two types are not compatible. On top of that, int.Parse *expects* a string parameter and you are attempting to pass an int.

As far as I can see, all you need here is

```
txtsalary = Salary.ToString();
```